# establecer ruta según la ubicación de mi script en Python

Tags: python

Estoy buscando como establecer la ruta que se establece para poder trabajar con los archivos en `Python`, ejemplo:

```
os.chdir(r"D:\miubicacion\Pyton\Union de Tablas")
```

Pero lo que quiero es establecer dicha ruta automáticamente según la ubicación de mi script; he encontrado esto:

```
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me sale un error:

```
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

**Edit**:
He probado también con el siguiente código, pero no me asigna la ubicación del script, solo: `c\users\mi_usuario`

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

¿Pueden saber como solucionarlo o alguna forma de sacar la ruta de mi script?

Gracias!!!

Comment: No coincide el código que muestras con el error que dices que te sale. En tu código no usas `__file__`, sino `__dir__`. y el error que me sale al intentar ejecutar tu código es  `name '__dir__' is not defined`. Si cambio `__dir__` por `__file__` en el código, entonces ya me funciona. Pero según pones en tu error ¿a ti te dice que `__file__` no está definido? Aclara esto por favor.

Comment: Perdona, yo tengo __ file __, ya lo he corregido, pero me da error en __ file __; ¿puede ser por la versión de python? yo tengo la 3.3 de spyder... donde ponía __ dir __ tenía puesto __ file __ en el código, pero de probar y probar, lo puse mal aquí. :-)   Gracias!!

Comment: Cómo ejecutas el script? tiene pinta de ser un problema debido a que lo ejecutas desde algun IDE, o desde un interprete interactivo

Comment: El script lo ejecuto desde spyder, linea por linea. Estoy aprendiendo python, así que no tengo mucha idea de cual puede ser el problema. Gracias @abulafia!

Comment: Ese es el problema, el uso de spyder. Cuando ejecutas con F5 dentro de Spyder, la variable `__file__`  no está definida. Parece que [no se sabe claramente de quién es la culpa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52778687/1264820). Intentaré reproducir el problema a ver si se me ocurre alguna forma de resolverlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
import os

ruta_completa = os.getcwd()
print ruta_completa
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
espero te sirva..!!

Para mayor detalle visita la documentacion:
[getcwd()  Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_getcwd.htm)

Comment: Esta solucion dará como resultado la carpeta desde la que se ha lanzado el intérprete python, lo que no necesariamente coincide con la carpeta donde está el script `.py`, que es lo que el usuario preguntaba.

Comment: Vale, rectifico... no me funciona; sólo me funcionó porque anteriormente había indicado la ruta del script y volvía a cargar los datos indicando la ruta otra vez más abajo (esto en Jupyter...), pero si lo hago así desde un principio hace lo que dice @abulafia.  Gracias!

Comment: que version de python tienes

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el directorio donde se ejecutó el script:

```
import os

current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(current_path)
```

Comment: Gracias Felix, ese código es lo mismo que tengo yo y me da error en __ file __

Comment: probado en ubuntu + python3. Un detalle: si ejecutas `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` desde la shell interactiva no va a funcionar porque lo que hace este comando es detectar donde esta ubicado el .py ejecutado.